# Liquibase problem when inserting UUID value to PostgreSQL Database

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, database-migration, liquibase

I'm using Spring Boot 2 with Liquibase (Core 3.6.2) and my DB is PostgreSQL.
 I'm creating table by this changeset in my db.changelog-master.xml:

```
<changeSet author="system" id="1">
    <createTable tableName="test">
        <column name="id" type="UUID">
            <constraints nullable="false"/>
        </column>
        <column name="note" type="VARCHAR(4096)"/>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

The next changeset used to insert values to this table from csv file:

```
<changeSet author="system" id="2">
    <loadData encoding="UTF-8" file="classpath:liquibase/data/test.csv" quotchar="&quot;" separator="," tableName="test">
        <column header="id" name="id" type="STRING" />
       <column header="note" name="note" type="STRING"/>
    </loadData>
</changeSet>
```

If i specify type UUID in column **id** instead of STRING the liquibase will tell me:

```
loadData type of uuid is not supported. Please use BOOLEAN, NUMERIC, DATE, STRING, COMPUTED or SKIP
```

The content of **test.csv** file:

```
"id","note"
"18d892e0-e88d-4b18-a5c0-c209983ea3c0","test-note"
```

When i run application, liquibase created table and when it try to insert values i get this message:

```
ERROR: column "id" is of type uuid but expression is of type character varying
```

The problem is in class ExecutablePreparedStatementBase that is located in liquibase-core dependency, and rows of method in this class that create this error:

```
private void applyColumnParameter(PreparedStatement stmt, int i, ColumnConfig col) throws SQLException,
        DatabaseException {
    if (col.getValue() != null) {
        LOG.debug(LogType.LOG, "value is string = " + col.getValue());
        stmt.setString(i, col.getValue());
    }
```

Liquibase used JDBC and PreparedStatement for executing queries.  The problem is because type of column of table **test** is **uuid**, and liquibase tried to insert **string**. And if we manually insert values to this table by using JDBC we should use `setObject` method of `PreparedStatement` instead of `setString`. But how can i fix this problem if this problem located in liquibase-core.jar? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was very hurts, but i found solution. You need to specify parameter `stringtype=unspecified` in your JDBC URL property. For example in application.properties:

```
spring.liquibase.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres?stringtype=unspecified
```

I hope this answer will help someone.

Comment: A cleaner solution would be to alter liquibase, but this is a nice workaround. If you aren't able to create a pull request for this, could you at least file a bug with Liquibase?

Comment: @SteveDonie ok, i will try create pull request with bug improvement. But how can i "file a bug"? The first time I hear this)))

Comment: Liquibase uses JIRA for bug/feature tracking - see https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues

Comment: There is a bug-report now: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-3214 No response for quite a while though.